# Re-access output from executing script

Tags: bash, unix

I have a process that executes on a remote server that I access through the terminal via my employer's VPN. The VPN connection terminates every 12 hours and requires that I re-enter my password to reconnect. This unfortunately cuts off the terminal output of my script when I reconnect. **Is it possible to re-access my script's terminal output after the connection has been severed?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try GNU screen. It can preserve sessions while the connection is off.

Comment: Also look at tmux as a more modern replacement for screen.